# How do I add a background to my scene? SpriteKit Swift 4

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am making a endless runner game using `SpriteKit`. When I run the game, the background is black, and I've tried 3 methods on how to change the background, but it still is black. The code for my scene is

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
   // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
   let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)
   scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
   view.presentScene(scene)

   view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
   view.showsFPS = true
   view.showsNodeCount = true
}
```

I want to replace the black background with this:

[image: background]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: "I am making a endless runner game using SpriteKit"  That's not what your title suggests.

Comment: Read the rest of the question

Comment: Oops. My title said SceneKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GameScene.swift` file, put the following code in your `didMove(to:)` method:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 199.0/255.0, green: 246.0/255.0, blue: 248.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Also make sure that you are not already setting the background color in some other way.

Comment: This will work for now, but sometimes I have images that I want to set the background to because they have things like lines in them

Comment: Sure, this works for a solid color but for images you would need to handle it in a very different way. You should make a separate question when you come to that part.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image you want to make be your background, make a SKSpriteNode object with parameters that take in the name of your image within your assets.xcassets folder.

If your background doesnt fill the whole screen, use the setScale(multiplier) function on it to enlarge it. Resolution might be affected depending on how high resolution your image is/how large it is to start with.

Then add the SKSpriteNode with the addChild(SKSpriteNode) function. Ideally do this last part within your didMove(to:view) function.